# Windows 7 dual boots after upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, boot, multi-boot

I was running Vista 64, I installed (not upgraded, fresh install) Windows 7 64 bit on the same partition, but since then it's been bringing up a dual boot menu asking if I want to boot to 7 or Vista.  Any way to get rid of that, I'm really not interested in rolling back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BCDEdit to remove the entry you don't want.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I still use EasyBCD 1.72, which is afaik, the last freeware version. It works under XP, Vista and W7. I suggest this as an alternative.

PS. If punctuation really matters to the powers that be, I'd like to point out the following spelling error on the site. It's "I'd like to improve my answer!" not "I'd Like to improve my answer!"